# Search and replace with regex and sublime text

Tags: regex, replace, full-text-search, sublimetext

I need to find all of the instances of the following pattern:

```
<(h1|p) class="veronaText hidden" (.*?)>(Answer:|)</(h1|p)>
```

and replace it to add an ID and an extra class. How can I replace it so that it keeps its current formatting and attributes (h1 or p, etc)?

Comment: Can you mention your working language?

Comment: Not sure it is relevant?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<(h1|p) class="veronaText hidden" (.*?)>(Answer:|)</(h1|p)>
```

becomes

```
<$1 id="newID" class="veronaText hidden newClass" $2>$3</$4>
```

each $n represents a submatch within the main match, in the order they appear.